# STOMP with custom properties in Lua

Tags: activemq-classic, stomp

I am trying to put two custom properties in a STOMP message header when publishing a topic message so that a subscriber can filter messages. Here are two frames that I send to ActiveMQ 5.14 to connect and publish:

```
CONNECT
login: myUserName
passcode: myPassword
```

**Note**: Actual string is `CONNECT\nlogin: myUserName\npasscode: myPassword`.

and

```
SEND
destination:/topic/myTopic

myTopicMessage
```

**Note**: Actual string is `SEND\ndestination:/topic/myTopic\n\nmyTopicMessage`.

How am I supposed to add the following two pairs of properties to above strings?

```
package_code = ''
whse_code = 'MyWarehouse'
```

BTW, I am using lua to implement this.

Comment: Justin, I found that the cause of the issue is on the selector on the subscriber side. The issue is around empty package_code. In the topic message I used "package_code:" which has no value after the colon(:). The condition on subscriber's selector cannot handle it. So the solution was to change the selector condition to (package_code = '' OR package_code IS NULL) as you suggested AND remove "package_code:" in topic messages when publishing. Thank you so much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the properties to your `SEND` frame with the same syntax used by `destination`, e.g.:

```
SEND
destination:/topic/myTopic
package_code:MyPackageCode
whse_code:MyWarehouse

myTopicMessage^@
```

If `package_code` (or any other header) is blank simply don't set it.

A few other details are worth noting:

- Be sure to follow the body of the message with the NULL octet as noted in the ["STOMP Frames" section of the STOMP 1.2 spec](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#STOMP_Frames). The example above uses `^@` (i.e. control-@ in ASCII) to represent the NULL octet.
- `SEND` frames *should* include a [content-length](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Header_content-length) header and a [content-type](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Header_content-type) header if a body is present as noted in the ["SEND" section of the STOMP 1.2 spec](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#SEND).

**Troubleshooting:**

You can enable STOMP protocol tracing with the following steps:

- ActiveMQ 5.x: Set `trace=true` on the STOMP `transportConnector`, e.g.: `<transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://localhost:61613?trace=true"/>`. Then set the `org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompIO` logger to `TRACE` in `conf/log4j.properties`
- [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/): Set the logger `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp.StompConnection` to `DEBUG` in `etc/logging.properties`.

Comment: Yes, the message body ends with '\0' which is ^@. I have added 'content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8' to the header. 'package_code:' was in the header because there is no value. But the result is the same. It posts successfully but a subscriber doesn't consume the message. Is there any way that I can actually see submitted string in ActiveMQ log. I turned on logging but could not find it. When I added content-length it failed to post. I guess the length was wrong. But it should not matter if it's not in the header because it's optional.

Comment: SEND\ndestination:/topic/MyTopic\ncontent-type:application/json;charset=utf-8\npackage_code:\nwarehose_code:W1\n\nMyJsonDataHere\0

Comment: Is the subscriber using a selector? This part of your use-case wasn't really covered in the original question.

Comment: I added some info to my answer about how to log STOMP frames.

Comment: Did the logging reveal anything helpful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209168/discussion-between-tim-and-justin-bertram).